# JS/Ajax/Jquery consecutive requests through linked list

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, loops, while-loop

My code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var x = 1;
    var data  = JSON.parse( document.getElementById('json').innerHTML);
    var next = data['next'];
    var jsonData = data['data'];
    
    while (next != null) {
      x = x+1;
      var nextFileUrl = data['next'];
      console.log('next:', nextFileUrl);
      
      const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", function () {
        if (this.readyState === this.DONE) {
          data = this.response;
          next = JSON.parse(this.response)['next'];
          console.log('newNext:',next);
          newJsonData = JSON.parse(this.response)['data'];
          console.log('newJsonData:',newJsonData);
          jsonData['data'].push(newJsonData);
        }
      });
      xhr.open("GET", nextFileUrl);
      xhr.send(null);  
                
    }
  </script>
```

Data example:

```
{
"next" : "path2",
"data" : "some data here"
}
```

I have multiple JSON files described as above that I need to access consecutively, in a "while next != null" kind of loop, starting with the data that's already in the page. For every call, I need to get the data value, and do something with it, and then make the next call. Currently, my code seems to constantly be logging the result from the first response only.

I'm fairly new to javascript and ajax, and have no experience with jquery. I can't use fetch, as I need the solution to work for all browsers. I'm looking for the best solution to this between JS, Ajax and JQuery if someone can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score -1):

Your sending async requests in a while loop and expecting a value to update each iteration, but that will never work since the loop will not wait for the request to complete. Rather than a loop, you can call a function recursively until the condition is satisfied

```
var x = 1;
var data = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('json').innerHTML);
var next = data['next'];
var jsonData = data['data'];

function cycle() {
  if (!next) return;
  x = x + 1;
  var nextFileUrl = next;
  console.log('next:', nextFileUrl);

  const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", function() {
    if (this.readyState === this.DONE) {
      data = this.response;
      next = JSON.parse(this.response)['next'];
      console.log('newNext:', next);
      newJsonData = JSON.parse(this.response)['data'];
      console.log('newJsonData:', newJsonData);
      jsonData['data'].push(newJsonData);

      // call the function 
      if (next) cycle();
    }
  });
  xhr.open("GET", nextFileUrl);
  xhr.send(null);

}
```